# How do I name a partition?

Tags: linux-mint, mount, partition, nautilus

Currently, I have a partition where Crunchbang is installed, which shows up as a folder in Mint named either `0d71227f-66fc-45ac-8bfc-93280b93dc8c` or "10.0 GB Volume".

First question is, of course, wtf?

My main question is, however, how do I rename it to something less ridiculous?  I tried renaming it as root, and I get the `device is busy` error.

Comment: You can either label the partition or use `x-gvfs-name=` in `/etc/fstab` to display the partition under a certain name in the file manager, see [here](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/169305).

Answer (score 4):

These names usually do not refer to the partition (which would make sense with LVM / DM only) but to the file system. Every file system (of certain types) has a UUID (0d71227f-66fc-45ac-8bfc-93280b93dc8c) but not everyone has a name. For ext3 and ext4 you can see the volume name with `dumpe2fs -h /dev/whatever`. You can set it with `tune2fs -L`.

Comment: ... or GParted. The "name" of the partition is called the label.

Comment: @ignis But that is valid for GPT partitions only, not for MBR partitions.

Comment: No, it's valid for both

Comment: @ignis Can you explain how that is supposed to work? Neither is room in the MBR partition table entries for a label nor do `fdisk` and `sfdisk` (apparently) offer you to set such a label.

Comment: You can edit labels in Gparted, and see them with blkid

Comment: @ignis "This option works only on Mac, PC98, and GPT disklabels."

Comment: On MBR, labels are stored inside the filesystem, provided that the filesystem supports a label. You can use filesystem-specific tools, like e2label, or Gparted, that runs them for you. [Gparted Manual, Setting a partition label](http://gparted.sourceforge.net/display-doc.php?name=help-manual#gparted-setting-partition-label) // [Gparted Features Support table](http://gparted.sourceforge.net/features.php) which you can also see via the "View" >> "File system support" menu.

Comment: @ignis You are confusing file system labels with partition labels.

Comment: Yeah, technically, you are right because you're writing about a partition label, but a filesystem can be labelled too. That's why parted returns error - it does not deal with the filesystem. But this point is moot, since nobody is going to use a partition without a filesystem inside.

Comment: GParted is retarded for naming mounted partitions. Use tune2fs -L <name of Label> </dev/sd_??#>.  (eg. tune2fs Dune /dev/sda8). You can even do this while Gparted is running. Refresh Gparted and it will see your change.

Answer (score 1):

In order to mount a partition, your file manager (Nautilus, Dolphin, Thunar) exec something like:

```
blkid /dev/sdaN
```

in which output appear the UUID "0d71227f-66fc-45ac-8bfc-93280b93dc8c" of that partition, the file manager use that UUID to create a temporal directory where is going to mount the partition. The UUID is unique so each partition will have a different one. Be careful in the N, since represent the partition number, always you can exec `fdisk -l` to know your partition table.

So to answer your question, you can create a directory like /media/CrunchbangDisk where you can mount manually your partition.

Here an example:

```
mkdir /media/CrunchbangDisk
mount /dev/sdaN /media/CrunchbangDisk
```

Also you can specify the partition type with, e.g. `-t ext2` to the mount command.