# Do entries in /etc/fstab control what points devices partitions are automatically mounted to?

Tags: linux, mount, fstab

My question is about how to change the points where devices and partitions automatically mount to upon being detected.

The file `/etc/fstab` contains the entry

```
/dev/fd0    /media/floppy0  auto    rw,user,noauto,exec,utf8    0   0
```

for mounting floppy disks at `/media/floppy0`. I don't have a floppy drive on my computer, so I don't know the behavior of this. But, I have also included this line in my `fstab` file:

```
/dev/sr0    /CDROM  udf,iso9660 user,noauto,exec,utf8   0   0
```

I want to know if this will make CDs mount at `/CDROM` instead of some point in `/media/<user>`.

Comment: You do know that `/dev/fd0` isn't the CD-ROM right?

Comment: @Gabriel I fixed it.

Comment: You specified `noauto` so the CDROM will **not** automatically get mounted.

Comment: `/etc/fstab` has priority... See also [What is the difference between mounting in fstab and by mounting in file manager](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/169571)

Answer (score 1):

The `mount` command looks at `/etc/fstab`, but there is no requirement that an arbitrary command that mounts a filesystem has to look at `/etc/fstab`. And there are many such commands.

From `man mount`

```
If only the directory or the device is given, for example:

              mount /dir

       then  mount  looks  for  a mountpoint (and if not found then for a device) in the /etc/fstab file.
```

In particular, software for automatically mounting filesystems may not issue a `mount` command. So, no. You need to look at the particular software that is doing the mounting.

If you give more information about how your automatic mounting is configured, then it may be possible to give more specific information.

Comment: The operating system is Ubuntu 15.10.

Comment: Yes, but how is your automounting configured? Looking at the logs when you plug in a device will probably tell you. Try `/var/log/messages` and `/var/log/syslog` to start with.