# Possible to mount to "/mnt/" instead of "/run/media/$USER/" on Linux?

Tags: linux, mount, automounting

Can the mount path be changed to "/mnt" since this is a system only used by a single person.

---

Edit, seems this is using udisks2

Comment: If you're talking about auto-mounting with `udisks` then no, you can't change the mount point to `/mnt` (unless you're willing to [patch the source code](https://github.com/storaged-project/udisks/blob/master/src/udiskslinuxfilesystem.c)). You can only change  the default mount point to `/media` if you [set `UDISKS_FILESYSTEM_SHARED` to `1`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/169576)

Comment: If you are auto-mounting with udisks then no, you can't change the mount point to /mnt. You can only change the default mount point to /media if you set `UDISKS_FILESYSTEM_SHARED` to 1.

Answer (score 1):

From the Filesystem Hierarchy Standard:

> "This directory is provided so that the **system administrator** may
>   temporarily mount a filesystem as needed. The content of this
>   directory is a local issue and should not affect the manner in which
>   any program is run.
>
> This directory **must not** be used by installation programs: a
>   suitable temporary directory not in use by the system must be used
>   instead."

http://www.pathname.com/fhs/2.2/fhs-3.11.html

That temporary directory is /run/media/.

Answer (score 0):

You could try a bind mount the auto-mounted folders to the /mnt folder eg:

```
sudo sh -c "for dir in $(ls /media/$USER | grep -v floppy); do mkdir -p /mnt/$dir; mount --bind /media/$USER/$dir /mnt/$dir; done"
```

Or create a symlink:

```
ln -s /media/$USER/drivelabel /mnt/drivelabel
```