# x-gvfs-show: Cannot display second hard drive left side of nautilus

Tags: fstab, nautilus, udisks

I am trying to get fstab option `x-gvfs-show` to work as expected on my default installation of Debian/buster/amd64. I did stumble upon:

- [What is the difference between mounting in fstab and by mounting in file manager answer.](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/169576/32896)

but it does not seems to be working for me.

---

I did experiment with a remote CIFS network drive and can go from:

[image]

to:

[image]

Simply adding in `/etc/fstab` the following line:

```
$ tail -1 /etc/fstab
//freebox_server/freebox /media/freebox cifs rw,uid=1000,gid=1000,guest,defaults,noauto,x-systemd.automount,x-systemd.mount-timeout=30,_netdev,nobrl,iocharset=utf8,vers=1.0 0 2
```

If now I try with a second hard drive the same trick to mount disk under `/media`, I can neither get the following to work:

```
/dev/disk/by-uuid/4c0ec08d-da8b-4ea0-9d9d-2bc5ceb1fb66 /media/backup ext4 nosuid,nodev,nofail,noatime 0 2
```

nor:

```
/dev/disk/by-uuid/4c0ec08d-da8b-4ea0-9d9d-2bc5ceb1fb66 /media/backup ext4 nosuid,nodev,nofail,noatime,x-systemd.automount,x-gvfs-show 0 2
```

What am I missing ? For reference:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Option 1:

Navigate to the target mount point, and bookmark it.
Possibly not what you had initially in mind, but it works.
Source: https://askubuntu.com/a/1036779/226614

**Notes**:

1. Did you reboot your system since implementing changes?
2. Is your drive mounted?
3. There is a [related bug](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?pid=1779703#p1779703). What is you Gnome version? System/kernel?
   Many of these issues vary from version to version, so it is best if you post more details.

**Related**:

1. https://askubuntu.com/questions/1036773/nautilus-not-showing-mounted-drives-in-side-bar
2. https://www.reddit.com/r/linux4noobs/comments/cz8mbk/how_do_i_make_nautilus_show_mounted_drives_in_the/eza6r56/

Comment: Indeed the bookmark operation is close to what I had in mind. I did all of the above (reboot dance...). Since my `x-gvfs-show` is listed in `/etc/fstab` I believe this is different from the bug you referenced.

Comment: Note #3 is about mount(s) that are not listed in `/etrc/fstab`. Mine is listed in `/etc/fstab`.

Comment: Did you see my updated answer ? With the screenshot ? (I followed instructions from [here](https://help.gnome.org/users/gnome-help/stable/gnome-version.html.en))